# RangeError when trying to execute mongodb query with mongoose/mongodb-native

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a problem which has already cost me a couple of days and I totally fail to understand it. I use node.js and have a mongodb with places indexed for their coordinates. I verified that the index works fine beforehand. For a set of coordinates, I want to find the nearest place. Here's how I tried to go about it:

```
    var Places = require(./models/places.js),
        coordFinder = require('./coordFinder.js');

    ...

    function getCoords(userId, callback) {
       coordFinder.getCoords(userId, function(err, coords) {
          if (err) {
             callback(err);
          } else {   
             callback(null, coords);
          }
       }
    }

    function getNearestPlaces(coords, callback) {
       async.forEachSeries(
          coords,
          function(coord, done) {
             Places.findOne(
                { coordinates: { $near: [ coord.lat, coord.lon ] } },
                function(err, place) {
                   // do something with place
                   done();
                }
             )
          },
          function(err) {
             callback(err ? err : null);    
          }
       );
    }

    ...

    async.waterfall(
       [
          ...
          getCoords,
          getNearestPlaces,
          ...
       ],
       function(err) {
          ...
       }
    }
```

The mongodb query consistently fails with the following error message for the first query:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

When I change the query in `getNearestPlaces` to

```
... { $near: [ 10, 10 ] } ...
```

I as consistently get no error and the correct place. The same happens if I avoid the call to `coordFinder`in `getCoords` and change `getCoords` to

```
function getCoords(userId, callback) {
    callback(
        null, 
        [ 
           // some coordinates
        ]
    );
```

I know the error indicates a stack overflow (increasing the stack size didn't help) but I can't figure out how I could have caused one. Does anyone have a clue as to why this happens? Thanks in advance for your insights!

**Edit**: It got the same problem when using `mongodb-native` directly, by the way, so `mongoose` seems not to be the problem. One more clue - using the same query never gives me a problem when I don't call it from within a callback. Could that be a source of error?

I use

- node.js 0.6.14
- mongodb 2.2.2
- node module async 0.1.22
- node module mongodb 1.2.5
- node module mongoose 2.5.7

Cheers,
Georg

Comment: Do you using geospatial indexes?

Comment: Yes I do. Worked fine in the past and also works fine when executing queries from the mongo shell.

Comment: How many elements in the `coords` array when this is failing?

Comment: two actually. I tried it with only one and got the same error.

Comment: Maybe the coord values passed through aren't what you think they are.  Perhaps using $near: [ Number(String(coord.lat)), Number(String(coord.lon)) ] is worth a try.

Comment: hot damn - you are right mjhm. Using the conversion made it work. Thanks a bunch for pointing me in this direction. I checked the type of coord.lat with instanceof and it turns out it already was Number. Using coord.lat.valueOf() also solved the problem, by the way. I still don't get how using the Number object might have caused the infinite loop in the first place. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mjhm pointed me in the right direction. Apparently, the Number instanced passed to the mongoose query caused the stack overflow. I'm not sure why, but creating a new Number object from the old one (as mjhm suggested) or converting the number into a primitive with valueOf() solved the problem.

If anyone has a clue as to how the original Number object caused the stack overflow, I'd very much appreciate any insights you might have to offer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely coming from the hidden recursion of `async.forEachSeries`.  Try wrapping the `Places.findOne` call with `setTimeout` like this:

```
function getNearestPlaces(coords, callback) {
   async.forEachSeries(
      coords,
      function(coord, done) {
         setTimeout(function () {
             Places.findOne(
                 { coordinates: { $near: [ coord.lat, coord.lon ] } },
                 function(err, place) {
                     // do something with place
                     done();
                 }
             );
         }, 1);
      },
      function(err) {
         callback(err ? err : null);    
      }
   );
}
```

This puts the `Places.findOne` call outside of the call stack of `async.forEachSeries`.